# determine returned object is copy or deepcopy

Tags: python

I was thinking , what if, i has function which returns of copy or deepcopy of object depend on some logic. for random now.

```
from copy import copy,deepcopy
from random import choice


def just_copies(obj_to_copy):
    choices=[copy,deepcopy]
    func = choice(choices)
    return func(obj_to_copy)

some_list = [1,2,3,4,[5,6]]
copied_list = just_copies(some_list)
print("is ",copied_list," copy or deepcopy")
```

I was searching for answers, but can not find any other method than changing the list and  seeing the outcome.

Comment: I made a [package](https://github.com/Frank17/Mager) for determining the copy types of built-in containers (list, dict, etc.). It also works for nested containers. Checkout the examples in the README.md if you need to work on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the original list and returned list, and test if any of the elements are different.

```
is_deepcopy = any(x is not y for x, y in zip(some_list, copied_list))
```

You need to use `x is not y` because comparing lists with `!=` compares the contents recursively, not object identity.

Comment: For lists `some_list != copied_list` should work the same.

Comment: Yeah, they both work wrong. Need to check the IDs of the elements. @OlvinRoght

Comment: x  != y  this kinda comparison always be False, but i get the point.  is this the best way ?

Comment: @davi1ta I updated the answer.